# Non existence of the maximum likelihood estimator of the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood

For a random sample of size n of the normal distribution with unknown parameters $\theta = (\mu,\sigma^{2})$, we have the joint distribution:

$f_{n}(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \theta)=\frac{1}{\left(2 \pi \sigma^{2}\right)^{n / 2}} \exp \left[-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_{i}-\mu\right)^{2}\right]$

Now, the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for $\theta$ is usually obtained letting the gradient of the log of the joint distribution be 0 with respect to $\theta$, and taking the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$ which make the gradient cero. That gives the MLE:

$\hat{\theta}=\left(\hat{\mu}, \widehat{\sigma^{2}}\right)=\left(\bar{X}_{n}, \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{i}-\bar{X}_{n}\right)^{2}\right)$

In principle, this gives us the value of $\theta$ which maximise $f_{n}(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \theta)$ for a given data

Everything fine so far, but (following the example 7.5.10 in DeGroots's book [Probability and statistics](http://bio5495.wustl.edu/Probability/Readings/DeGroot4thEdition.pdf)), if we take $\mu=x_{k}$ to be one of the observed values, then making $\sigma^{2} \rightarrow 0$, the joint distribution will diverge $f_{n}\left(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \mu, \sigma^{2}\right) \rightarrow \infty$. Thus, it seems to imply that what we found is not the maximum, and that the normal distribution has no MLE for the parameter $\theta$.

I don't know what's going on. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot meaningfully estimate $\sigma^2$ from a single observation $x_k$ of a normal distribution.  The likelihood heads towards $\infty$ If you have $\mu=x_k$ and let $\sigma^2$ reduce towards $0$.  So in this particular example of a mixture distribution combining a standard normal and an unknown normal, you can get a positive constant likelihood for the other observations with the standard normal then multiplied by an unbounded likelihood for this observation, and so there is no maximum likelihood.

Comment: Alternatively you can say there is a maximum likelihood estimate corresponding to an infinite likelihood and variance $0$ for the unknown normal, but it turns out there are $n$ of them, one for each observation chosen to be the special case.  This is also unsatisfactory and unlikely to correspond to anything meaningful in reality.

Comment: This post confuses one particular *process* of minimizing a function (which *sometimes* can be carried out correctly by only examining zeros of a derivative) with its actual minimum.  The distinction often is overlooked, but in "edge cases" like the one described here, it is crucial to recognize it.